# How to get Laravel 5.7 seeded blade localization syntax to render in blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

My Seeder looks like this:

```
    class ContentTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void

     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('content')->insert(
            [
                [
                    'name'    => '<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <form method="get" action="/group-register">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="group_id" class="form-control" name="group_id" placeholder="{{ __(\'site.group_search\') }}">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{{ __(\'site.group_search_button\') }}</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <p>
            <a href="/group-register">{{ __('site.group_register') }}</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
</div>',
                    'title'      => 'home',
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                    'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
                ]                ]
        );
    }
}
```

Then I have a router that looks like this:

```
Route::get('/{title}', 'ContentController@show');
```

The controller:

```
class ContentController extends Controller
{

    public function show($id)
    {
        $content = Content::where('title', '=', $id)->get();
        return view('content.show', compact('content'));
    }
}
```

And the show.blade.php:

```
@section('content')
    <div class="main-content">
        @foreach($content as $item)
            {!! $item['name'] !!}
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endsection
```

And the output looks like this:
[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmbJa.png)

But if I call the same seeded code from basic blade.php then it looks correctly:

[this is how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J43f.png)

Comment: `{{ csrf_field() }}` `{{ __(\'site.group_search_button\') }}` and this `{{ __('site.group_register') }}` are only string

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
$content = Content::where('title', '=', $id)->get();
```

With this:

```
$content = Blade::compileString(Content::where('title', '=', $id)->get());
```

And dont forget to import the `Blade` facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
```